# A* (A Star) sliding block puzzle goes to infinite loop sometimes

Tags: java, infinite-loop, a-star

I've implemented the A* algorithm a while ago in Java and sometimes it solves my sliding block puzzle with more steps than it was initially shuffled, and sometimes it even goes to infinite loop. I've noticed that usually it goes to infinite loop when I increase the shuffling factor. The 8-puzzle doesn't present this problem, but starting with 4x3 or 15-puzzle and above almost 1/3 of the generated games fail miserably.

Just to be clear, I use a shuffling function to guarantee the generated games to be solvable and also remove the "back" move each time a shuffling movement is applied for better randomization (though it still makes full circles sometimes).

The heuristic function used is Manhattan distance.

It seems I've screwed up somewhere. Could anyone help me to understand why this is happening?

State:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(of="board")
public class State{
    @Getter @Setter private int[] board;
    @Getter @Setter private int g;
    @Getter @Setter private int h;
    @Getter @Setter private State parent;

    public State(int[] board){
        this.board = board;
    }

    public int getF(){
        return this.g + this.h;
    }
}
```

Game:

```
public abstract class Game{

    @Getter @Setter private int dimX;
    @Getter @Setter private int dimY;
    @Getter @Setter private int[] goalBoard;
    @Getter @Setter private int swaps;

    public int[] generateRandomGame(){
        int[] board = Utils.cloneBoard(goalBoard);
        List<Integer> possibleMoves;
        Integer nextMove = null;
        for(int i=0; i<swaps; i++){
            possibleMoves = Utils.getPossibleMoves(board, dimX, dimY);
            if(nextMove != null){
                switch(EnumMoveDirection.getById(nextMove.intValue())){
                case UP:
                    possibleMoves.remove(EnumMoveDirection.DOWN.getIntegerId());
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    possibleMoves.remove(EnumMoveDirection.LEFT.getIntegerId());
                    break;
                case DOWN:
                    possibleMoves.remove(EnumMoveDirection.UP.getIntegerId());
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    possibleMoves.remove(EnumMoveDirection.RIGHT.getIntegerId());
                    break;
                }
                possibleMoves.remove(nextMove);
            }
            nextMove = possibleMoves.get(new Random().nextInt(possibleMoves.size()));

            int startIndex = Utils.getStartPositionIndex(board);
            int tmp;
            switch(EnumMoveDirection.getById(nextMove.intValue())){
            case UP:
                tmp = board[startIndex];
                board[startIndex] = board[startIndex-dimX];
                board[startIndex-dimX] = tmp;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                tmp = board[startIndex];
                board[startIndex] = board[startIndex+1];
                board[startIndex+1] = tmp;
                break;
            case DOWN:
                tmp = board[startIndex];
                board[startIndex] = board[startIndex+dimX];
                board[startIndex+dimX] = tmp;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                tmp = board[startIndex];
                board[startIndex] = board[startIndex-1];
                board[startIndex-1] = tmp;
                break;
            }
        }
        return board;
    }
}
```

AStar:

```
public class AStar {
    private Game game;
    private List<State> openedStates = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<State> closedStates = new ArrayList<>();

    public AStar(Game game){
        this.game = game;
    }

    public List<State> solve(State startState){
        List<State> solutionStates = new LinkedList<>();
        State goalState = new State(game.getGoalBoard());

        startState.setG(0);
        startState.setH(calculateH(startState));
        openedStates.add(startState);

        State currentState = null;
        int g;
        while(!openedStates.isEmpty()){
            currentState = getStateWithMinF();

            if(currentState.equals(goalState)){
                State state = currentState;
                solutionStates.add(state);
                while(state.getParent() != null){
                    state = state.getParent();
                    solutionStates.add(cloneState(state));
                }
                break;
            }

            openedStates.remove(currentState);
            closedStates.add(currentState);

            for(State successorState : generateSuccessors(currentState)){
                if(closedStates.contains(successorState)){
                    continue;
                }

                g = currentState.getG()+1;

                if(!openedStates.contains(successorState)){
                    openedStates.add(successorState);
                }else if(g >= findState(successorState, openedStates).getG()){
                    continue;
                }

                successorState.setG(g);
                successorState.setH(calculateH(successorState));
                successorState.setParent(currentState);
            }
        }
        return solutionStates;
    }

    private State getStateWithMinF(){
        State bestState = null;
        int minF = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(State state : openedStates){
            if(minF > state.getF()){
                minF = state.getF();
                bestState = state;
            }
        }
        return bestState;
    }

    private int calculateH(State state){
        int h = 0;
        int dimX = game.getDimX();
        int length = state.getBoard().length;
        int[] board = state.getBoard();
        int[] hBoard = new int[length];
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
            hBoard[i] = Math.abs(i/dimX-getGoalPosition(board[i])/dimX) + Math.abs(i%dimX-getGoalPosition(board[i])%dimX);
            h += hBoard[i];
        }
        return h;
    }

    private int getGoalPosition(int num){
        int[] goalBoard = game.getGoalBoard();
        int length = goalBoard.length;
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
            if(goalBoard[i] == num){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private List<State> generateSuccessors(State state){
        List<State> successors = new ArrayList<>(4);
        int startIndex = Utils.getStartPositionIndex(state.getBoard());
        int tmp, dimX = game.getDimX();
        int[] board;
        for(Integer possibleMove : Utils.getPossibleMoves(state.getBoard(), dimX, game.getDimY())){
            board = Utils.cloneBoard(state.getBoard());
            switch(EnumMoveDirection.getById(possibleMove.intValue())){
            case UP:
                tmp = board[startIndex];
                board[startIndex] = board[startIndex-dimX];
                board[startIndex-dimX] = tmp;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                tmp = board[startIndex];
                board[startIndex] = board[startIndex+1];
                board[startIndex+1] = tmp;
                break;
            case DOWN:
                tmp = board[startIndex];
                board[startIndex] = board[startIndex+dimX];
                board[startIndex+dimX] = tmp;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                tmp = board[startIndex];
                board[startIndex] = board[startIndex-1];
                board[startIndex-1] = tmp;
                break;
            }
            successors.add(new State(board));
        }
        return successors;
    }

    private static State findState(State state, List<State> states){
        for(State item : states){
            if(item.equals(state)){
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static State cloneState(State state){
        State clone = new State(Utils.cloneBoard(state.getBoard()));
        clone.setG(state.getG());
        clone.setH(state.getH());
        return clone;
    }
}
```

Comment: Infinite loop in a-star indicates that you are not adding nodes to the closed list properly. Given that this is Java, I would double check that you've implemented `equals()` so that nodes/states with different parents are considered equal. By default, all fields in an object are compared when calculating `equals()`, which is going to cause problems sometimes.

Comment: Equals is already implemented by @EqualsAndHashCode(of="board"), that means it evaluates board field only, which is a deep hash of an int array, ignoring the rest of State class fields.